# Storing using malloc() or realloc() and printing data in C

Tags: c, malloc, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

Could someone please tell me about what is wrong with the code? Sorry if I'm new at this but I am trying to get this right for a long time. I am trying to get input from the user and then print the values. The following code is just an example.

I try to run the code but I get run-time errors. Can anyone pls help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct poly
{
    int kill;
    float bill;
    char katana[50];
} koly;
 typedef koly* terma;

int main()
{
        int count = 0;
        terma ren;
        ren = (terma)malloc(sizeof(koly));
        ren = (terma)realloc(6*sizeof(koly));
        printf("We can store now:\n\n");
        while(++count<= 2)
        {
            scanf("%d",ren->kill);
            scanf("%f",ren->bill);
            scanf("%s",ren->katana);
        }
        while(++count<= 2)
        {
            printf("\n%d\n",ren->kill);
            printf("\n%f\n",ren->bill);
            printf("\n%s\n",ren->katana);
        }
}
```

Comment: What run-time  error(s)?

Comment: realloc : two argument

Comment: ye gods, the satanic practice of casting the return value of `malloc` / `realloc` has taken a turn for the worse. `malloc` & co return `void *`, _a pointer_, you're casting it. _don't_, and especially using your `typedef` which obscures what you're actually doing anyway

Comment: not sure why you do realloc? it seems you are only reading 2 records (` ++count<=2 `) ? probably good to set count to 0 before printing though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your error:

```
scanf("%d",ren->kill);
scanf("%f",ren->bill);
```

These should be pointers, so the corrected version is:

```
scanf("%d",&ren->kill);
scanf("%f",&ren->bill);
```

Also, `realloc` expects 2 arguments unlike `malloc`. The first should be a pointer to the address you are reallocing, and the second should be the new size. So:

```
ren = realloc(ren, 6 * sizeof(koly));
```

I have two other things to say about your code. First: it is unnecessary to cast the return value of `malloc` in C (and is frowned upon). Also, NEVER use `scanf` with the `"%s"` format specifier. This is extremely insecure and can easily lead to crashes and worse. The best method is to use `fgets`, so `scanf("%s",ren->katana);` would become this:

```
fgets(ren->katana, sizeof(ren->katana), stdin);
```

Edit:
Here is my explanation for why casting the return value of `malloc`/`realloc` should be avoided:

It's not really because it's *wrong*; it's because it is bad practice to do so in C. Since a `void*` type is automatically converted to any pointer type, the typecasting is superfluous, the code is less readable (IMO), and it makes changes more difficult. For example, take your case:

```
ren = (terma)malloc(sizeof(koly));
```

I personally would rewrite this line like so:

```
ren = malloc(sizeof(*ren));
```

This allows for easily changing the type of `ren`. If `ren` were changed to another data type (such as `int*` or `struct sockaddr_in*` or anything else), it would automatically work. You wouldn't need to change the type in the cast or the type in the `sizeof()`. Both will automatically work for the new type. For arrays, it works the same:

```
int* myArr = malloc(42 * sizeof(*myArr));
```

If I instead wanted `myArr` to hold an array of 42 `float`s, the change is simple:

```
float* myArr = malloc(42 * sizeof(*myArr));
```

Note: In C++, the typecast is required as it doesn't automatically convert `void*` to other pointer types, but you really shouldn't be using `malloc` et al in C++ anyways when you have `new` (plus this is a C question, not C++).

Comment: Well, thank you everyone for your input and I appreciate it. Though I have another question. Why is it wrong to typecast the return value of malloc?

Answer (score 0):

Realloc() takes two arguments. how does it even compiled?

```
ren = (terma)realloc(ren,6*sizeof(koly));
```

You also need scanf corrected:

```
scanf("%d",&ren->kill);
scanf("%f",&ren->bill);
```

But just word of caution: You are over-writing your only one object.

Comment: Why is it that I will be overwriting the subject exactly? Shouldn't the code(corrected version of course) store the input to the structure's individual members? Also say that overwriting would be occurring would this cause some errors with allocating memory on the heap?

Comment: @user3134098 because you are running the code to write _ren->kill_ in while loop, and it will be called more than once for sure. Hence overwritting last times value. whereas you propably meant to use ren[0] for rist time and ren[1] for second time and so on.. if you debug you will come to know.

Answer (score 0):

void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);

realloc takes two arguments, the prototype is as above, what you have missed in your code is to give the pointer for which you want to reallocate the memory.

you have to use, ren = (terma)realloc( rem, 6*sizeof(koly));

and another error is you have missed & operator in scanf function, it should be,        scanf("%d",&ren->kill);

And its not the run time error, did you get the code compiled correctly...?